# Spring transaction management using JDBC and Hibernate 4 together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

We are using JPA (Hibernate 4) with Spring 4 managing the JTA transactions. Since there are parts of the application using JDBC to access the database as well, we need to make sure JDBC and JPA join the same transaction to see what the other changed **before** commit.

You can find a test case for these questions on GitHub https://github.com/abenneke/sandbox/tree/master/spring-hibernate4-transaction

To have JDBC and JPA join the same transaction and see the changes the other made, we had to use the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` for Hibernate/JPA as well. With all the other transaction configuration around, this however seems to be redundant. Did we miss something? Or is this the suggested way to achieve the requirement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you can achieve the same outcome with much less configuration hassle if you stock to Hibernate and your JTA DataSource while you use the Session.[doWork](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) for your JDBC code.
2. You don't need TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy, since you want to use Transaction services anyway and not call DAO classes outside of a transactional service.
3. You need to add:

   ```
   <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
   ```

   and make sure you supply it to testEntityManager

   ```
   <bean id="testEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource">
        ...
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
   </bean>
   ```

### Update

In one application we developed recently we too mixed JPA and JDBCTemplate and it worked nicely because Bitronix PoolingDataSource was instructed to always return the same connection for the current running thread.

For this you have to set the following [Bitronix property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/JdbcConfiguration2x):

```
shareTransactionConnections=true
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. However configuring the `HibernateJpaDialect` not does not change anything; Spring selects this dialect automatically if not configured (default in `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`). And choosing `Session.doWork` for the JDBC part would introduce an unwanted dependency on the JPA implementation (Hibernate) into the codebase.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It is correct, that we could exchange the `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` with setting `shareTransactionConnections` to true in the BTM configuration. By doing so we would put yet another ThreadLocal in place, which seems to be quite an overhead to me compared to using the existing ThreadLocal via `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy`. So the benefit is rather limited?

Comment: In my opinion is a better approach since it doesn't depend on spring at all. It's the DataSource that does the trick for you. And it should work for JTA aggressive connection release.

Comment: As it only answered one part of the original post I stripped the question down to that question and accepted the answer... :-)